# factor not displayed as ordered when printing or viewing dataframe

Tags: r, survey, unordered

I have the following dataframe

```
print(sch.rate)

      Level  15-49 married before 15 y.o. (%) 20-49 married before 15 y.o. (%)
1    Higher                            17.94                            16.33
2 Preschool                            24.69                            24.69
3   Primary                            16.42                            15.02
4 Secondary                             8.60                             7.70
  20-49 married before 18 y.o. (%)
1                            33.15
2                            48.64
3                            45.34
4                            28.34
```

The problem is that the first variable is ordered, but when I `print` or `View` the dataframe, it is not ordered, as you can see from above.

Everything looks fine regarding `class` and `levels`:

```
> class(sch.rate)
[1] "data.frame"

> class(sch.rate$Level)
[1] "ordered" "factor" 

> levels(sch.rate$Level)
[1] "Preschool" "Primary"   "Secondary" "Higher"
```

I did not get any error message when I converted the variable into an ordered factor (If anything would have gone wrong, I guess I would see it when enquiring on `class` and `levels` of the variable). I used the following code:

```
sch.rate$Level <- ordered(sch.rate$Level, levels = c("Preschool", 
"Primary", "Secondary", "Higher"))
```

What am I missing?

Many thanks

Manolo

EDIT 1:
I am not using any specific framework. The dataframe is a contingency table which was created using `svytable` from the `survey` package. I converted the `svytable` object into a dataframe and then changed it from long to wide using `spread`.

```
sch.a <- round(prop.table(svytable(~schooling+mar.uni.15, design = wm.svy), 1)*100, 2)
sch.a <- as.data.frame(sch.a)
sch.a <- spread(sch.a, key = mar.uni.15, value = Freq)

sch.b <- round(prop.table(svytable(~schooling+mar.uni.15, design = wm.svy.20), 1)*100, 2)
sch.b <- as.data.frame(sch.b)
sch.b <- spread(sch.b, key = mar.uni.15, value = Freq)

sch.c <- round(prop.table(svytable(~schooling+mar.uni.18, design = wm.svy.20), 1)*100, 2)
sch.c <- as.data.frame(sch.c)
sch.c <- spread(sch.c, key = mar.uni.18, value = Freq)
```

I dropped the columns unnecessary to me from the temporary dataframes `sch.a`, `sch.b`, and `sch.c`, renamed rows and columns and merged the three temporary dataframes:

```
sch.a$No <- NULL
sch.b$No <- NULL
sch.c$No <- NULL

sch.a <- `colnames<-`(sch.a, c("Level", "15-49 married before 15 y.o. (%)"))
sch.b <- `colnames<-`(sch.b, c("Level", "20-49 married before 15 y.o. (%)"))
sch.c <- `colnames<-`(sch.c, c("Level", "20-49 married before 18 y.o. (%)"))

sch.rate <- merge(sch.a, sch.b)
sch.rate <- merge(sch.rate, sch.c)
```

The result of all of this is what you can see at the beginning of the post.

Comment: What language are you working in? What framework (if any)? Please edit your question to add relevant tags. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Level` factor being ordered does not automatically mean that your data.frame will become ordered, you need to 'tell' it to be ordered. You can do this based on your order of the levels in `Level` though. I think that the following code should achieve what I think you want

```
sch.rate <- sch.rate[order(sch.rate$Level),]
```

Comment: that works splendidly. many thanks!